# How write text to File by Encode UTF-8?

Tags: extendscript

My code write Text to file in Adobe Script (.jsx):

```
 var xml=  " 小塚ゴシック Pro"

  var file = new File(output);
  file.open("w");   
  file.write(xml);
  file.close();
```

But result encode UTF-8 can't display:    `ϬӋēĖĢĎ Pro`
It only can display text  `" 小塚ゴシック Pro"` , if set encode of file is `Shift-JIS`.

How write text to File by Encode UTF-8?

Comment: jsx isn't Javascript. Assuming you tagged the question to a wrong place, updating it for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
file.encoding = "UTF-8";
```

And [here](https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript/wiki/Create-And-Read-Files) is a sample, for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with polish chars and had to use UTF-16 vs UTF-8.

```
var xml= "小塚ゴシック Pro"   
var file = new File(output);
file.encoding = "UTF-16";
file.open("w");   
file.write(xml);
file.close();
```